# Disabling copy function in UITextView not working

Tags: objective-c, ipad, xcode5, uitextview

I have a xib which includes a hidden UITextView until I click a button which makes the textview visible.

I want to disable copy just for the uitextview when the text is highlighted.

I've tried a few things, including

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{

    if (action == @selector(copy:))
        return NO;


    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

however, this doesn't do anything. I've tried to unhide it on load, but it still doesn't work.
I've also found that it doesn't work for anything else in that associated xib. I can still copy any other text.

Anyone have an idea as to why?

Comment: Where is the code that you have put here?

Comment: I placed this in the .m of the class associated with the xib, but it doesn't seem to work for anything. The copy function still works

Comment: I think, shouldn't this be in the actual `UITextView`? Isn't it the `UITextView` that performs the copy/paste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just disable Selectable property on the Interface Builder and the text will not be available to copy from the control.

Comment: i just saw that option a few seconds ago...can't believe i didn't know that was there this whole time. haven't used xibs in a while, thanks!